# Determine if a spike in the data is signal or noise

Tags: noise

I have a capacitive touch sensor that briefly engages every 15 seconds. The spikes sometimes happen when other parts of the device are touched, but sometimes happen on their own. The grey bar in the image below outlines a spike where the touch sensor engaged.

[image: Line graph of sensor readings with a spike outlined by a grey bar]

The spike is so narrow (only lasts for one time step, or about ten milliseconds) that I think it must be noise, but it's also larger than other spikes. The image below is a histogram of the change in subsequent sensor readings when the sensor is not being touched (n = 15,000).

[image: histogram of change in subsequent sensor readings]

The spike in the first image is about 110 counts. There are only ten spikes in the series that are larger than this. Is it possible to determine whether these large spikes are from random noise, or whether they are caused by something else (eg the device housing being touched)?

Comment: Why not run the experiment?  Study the spikes that arise from touching the sensor.

Comment: The goal of this experiment was to see if I could trigger the sensor by touching the device housing, and it was inconclusive - I wasn't sure if touching the device housing has an effect, or if it's just random noise (hence my question). The spikes are 50x smaller than the signals I get when I touch the actual sensor.

Comment: If you have no basis for comparing what you see to what is known either to be pure noise or known to be real spikes, then you have no basis for discriminating spikes from noise in your data.